# Git: gitolite have mess things up? working on two different servers

Tags: git, repository, git-push, gitolite

I am new in using Git, so here is my context: I am in a situation in which I work on two projects which are stored in different repositories on different servers. On both servers is used gitolite to handle the administration on the repositories.

When I had one project to handle I push the commits to the server with the command: `git push --all git@myserver1.com:project1` and it was OK. Now, when I handle two projects, I thought that it should be OK, if I am using the same command, only changing the server name and project, to deploy it on the server.

However is not OK, now when I write `git push --all git@myserver2.com:project2` (I am running this command from root folder of the project) is asking me for the password: `git@myserver2.com's password:` and after I type a password I get: `Permission denied (publickey,password).` But this behavior is not right because I already have set my public key on this second server.

I don't know where is the problem, maybe gitolite have mess things up? Combining on my PC the configuration for the two servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I write `git push --all git@myserver2.com:project2` (I am running this command from root folder of the project) is asking me for the password.

That means your public key hasn't been pushed to the gitolite repo of `myserver2`.
You need to [add it to your local `gitolite-admin` repo, in the `keydir` directory](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/2-admin.mkd#_adding_users_and_repos), and push that repo to `myserver2`, in order for gitolite to add it to the `.ssh/authorizedkeys` file.

For myserver1 or myserver2, you need to be able to type:

```
ssh git@myserver2.com
```

and have your gitolite ACL displayed.
If you don't see those rights (if you need to enter your password), then something is still wrong.

Comment: I see the ACL displayed, all is ok now. I think there was some right access problem on the server, because I have _play_ with that before.